# Using Arduino with MCP23S17 SPI I/O Expander

Tags: arduino

I am trying to use the SPI IO Expander to read off some BCD Switches. I am getting some very... funky and unexpected results. I am printing the read in digit to the serial Line. My problem is, digits 0,1,2,3 read in fine, but for some reason 4 is displaying as a 3, and then 5 as a 4 and so on... up to 9 showing as an 8. Here is the bit of code i am using:

```
int bDigit = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Serial.print(mcp.digitalRead(bcd1[i]));

    if (!mcp.digitalRead(bcd1[i])) {
      bDigit = bDigit + (int)pow(2, i);
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Binary Digit is ");
  Serial.println(bDigit);
  delay(5000);
```

since I am using a common ground for my BCD switches, and I have externally pulled up the IO lines with 10k resistors, The serial line returns the following:

When BCD is in position 3, Serial Displays

> 0011
>   Binary Digit is 3

When BCD is in position 4, Serial Displays

> 1101
>   Binary Digit is 3

The bcd in position 3 looks fine, first 2 bits are grounded and second 2 are high so the for loop will add 1 + 2, but the second example! 1101 will add pow(2,2)=4 ! so why is it outputting a 3!?!?!

I have included all my code below:

```
    #include <SPI.h>              // We use this library, so it must be called here.
    #include <MCP23S17.h>         // Here is the new class to make using the MCP23S17 easy.
MCP mcp(0, 10);            // Instantiate an object called "mcp" on an MCP23S17 device at address 0
                           // and slave-select on Arduino pin 10 to avoid the speed penalty of digitalWrite
int fEdgeTrig;
int bcd1[] = {8, 10, 7, 9};

void setup() {
  mcp.begin();
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    mcp.pinMode(bcd1[j], INPUT);
  }
  mcp.pinMode(1, INPUT);
  fEdgeTrig = 0;
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int bDigit = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Serial.print(mcp.digitalRead(bcd1[i]));

    if (!mcp.digitalRead(bcd1[i])) {
      bDigit = bDigit + (int)pow(2, i);
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Binary Digit is ");
  Serial.println(bDigit);
  delay(5000);
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, also I am a programming noob so be gentle :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about hardware which is not proven to work as expected. It might be better suited on electronics, but first check their rules!

Comment: And Arduino is not C nor exactly C++!

Comment: thanks for the help, ill try over there, sorry for posting in the wrong place, i just felt like my software/math was off. but your right it could be hardware related...

Comment: Hint: did you check the signal levels? Use a multi-/voltmeter. Some of those encoder-switches have strange connections internally. First make sure your hardware is working correct, then the software! Next check the SPI interface.